# file lastModified() changes by itself

Tags: java, android, sqlite, file-io

having some trouble with **file.lastModified()** under Android OS.
I developed a file synchronization app which relies on correct detection of file changes.

Heres the problem: Although the method of retrieving the modification timestamp is the same throughout the app every now and then different times are read even if the file wasn't touched at all. **Those readings differ after a day or two but never directly after one reading.**

Now the funny thing is that the offset between previous and actual readings are in my case exactly 2 hours. For me, two hours is my offset to GMT. OK - so far no idea.

Story continues: Some days later I read back another wrong value but now the offset is negative so I am back to my old (correct) value.

I can't provide much code because there is practically none. I read out lastModified() as long and store it in a SQLite database. Then compare those values later.

So I have a whole bunch of **questions**:

- Is it even possible that Android reports other values than GMT
  timestamps?
- How can my files modified date change by exactly two hours without
  altering the file?
- Does anyone know how to track down what causes that modification date
  to change or how the offset occures?

Thanks!

Comment: I continued testing...it is switching between correct reading and incorrect readings with 2 hours offset every couple of hours. Any ideas, please?

Comment: Found the reason by now?